# how to add drop down list to a fare calculator

Tags: php, jquery, google-maps, calculator, fare

Im trying to build a tow truck fare calculator, I found a script on here earlier, I modified it and it seems to be calculating fine, But now I need to add a drop down to it and calculate based on what selected.

Saying it quick, I need to know what we towing, if it is a car, the rate is 1.10 per mile made, If a van the rate is 1.30 per mile made and so on...

How do I take whats selected in drop down and calculate the fare?

I have litle php skills, so any comment appreciated.

```
<?php
session_start();
$rate = 1.10;
$fix = 75;
$callout = 65;
//}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Taxi Fare Calculation using PHP with GOOGLE MAPS API V3</title>
<style type="text/css">
html {
    height: 100%
}
body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    font-family:tahoma;
    font-size:8pt;
}
#total {
    font-size:large;
    text-align:center;
    font-family:Georgia, “Times New Roman”, Times, serif;
    color:#990000;
    margin:5px 0 10px 0;
    font-size:12px;
    width:374px;
}
input {
    margin:5px 0px;
    font-family:tahoma;
    font-size:8pt;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=places"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
      var map = null;
      var directionDisplay;
      var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

      function initialize() {
        directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();

        var Dublin = new google.maps.LatLng(53.349805,-6.260310);

        var mapOptions = {  
                    center              : Dublin,
                    zoom                : 4,
                    minZoom             : 3,
                    streetViewControl   : false,
                    mapTypeId           : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                    zoomControlOptions  : {style:google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.MEDIUM}
                };


        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),
            mapOptions);

         //Find From location    
    var fromText = document.getElementById('start');
    var fromAuto = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(fromText);
    fromAuto.bindTo('bounds', map);
    //Find To location
    var toText = document.getElementById('end');
    var toAuto = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(toText);
    toAuto.bindTo('bounds', map);
    //  
        directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
        directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById('directions-panel'));

        /*var control = document.getElementById('control');
        control.style.display = 'block';
        map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP].push(control);*/
      }

      function calcRoute() {
        var start = document.getElementById('start').value;
        var end = document.getElementById('end').value;
        var request = {
          origin: start,
          destination: end,
          travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
        };
        directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
          if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
            directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
            computeTotalDistance(response);
          }
        });
      }
      function computeTotalDistance(result) {
      var total = 0;
      var myroute = result.routes[0];
      for (i = 0; i < myroute.legs.length; i++) {
        total += myroute.legs[i].distance.value;
      }
      total = total / 1000;
      /*Start Calculating Distance Fair*/
          if (16>total){
          var cost = <?php echo $fix; ?>;
          }
          else if (17<total && 700>total)
            {
            var cost = ((total * <?php echo $rate; ?>) + (<?php echo $callout; ?>));
            }


          var fare = cost;
          var fare = Math.round(fare*100)/100;
      /*Distance Fair Calculation Ends*/

      document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = "Total Distance = " + total + " km and FARE = $" + fare;
      }

    function auto() {
    var input = document.getElementById[('start'), ('end')];
    var types
    var options = {
       types: [],
       componentRestrictions: {country: ["IE"]}
        };
        var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
     }

      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
</head>
<body onLoad="initialize()">
<table width="380px" border="2" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bordercolor="#FF9F0F" style="border-collapse:collapse">
  <tr>
    <td bgcolor="#FFFF99" style="padding:5px;">
    <table width="375px" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tr>
          <td><div id="map_canvas" style="width: 374px; height: 300px; border: solid 1px #336699"></div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><div id="form" style="width:374px; text-align:center; border: solid 1px #336699; background:#d1e1e4;">
              From:
                <input type="text" id="start" size="60px" name="start" placeholder="Enter Location From">
                <br />
                To:
                <input size="60px" type="text" id="end" name="end" placeholder="Enter Destination ">
                <input type="button" value="Calculate" onClick="calcRoute();">
             <div id="total"></div>
             </div></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      </td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. Post some code as an example and maybe that will help clarify what your issue is. Would this be something that you'd want to do in clientside Javascript rather than PHP?

Comment: Apologies, Didn't even notice i did not paste the  code.

Answer (score 0):

You could start from this...

```
<form action="process.php" method='post'>

<select name="cars">
<option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
<option value="saab">Saab</option>
<option value="fiat">Fiat</option>
<option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>

<input type="submit" />

</form>
```

Then in process.php $_POST['cars'] would be equal to whatever was submitted. Then just add another dropdown with something like `<select name="prices">` and get $_POST['prices']

Comment: I wanted to have the drop down in the same file without using post method.

Comment: You would use java script then.